# How to find mobile location using IMEI number?

Tags: php, android, mobile, java-me, imei

I want to get the mobile location for old mobiles (like the Nokia 3310, etc.) which do not support Java/Android applications. I am thinking of using the IMEI number. Is there any PHP/Android/Java API that takes IMEI numbers and returns a mobile location? If not, is there another way?

Comment: you have posted same 1uestion 10 mins ago ..please try to edit and refine that question instead of asking again

Answer (score 2):

Why you need to get location based on IMEI number? you can use `Location API` for both android and Java ME applications. Look on these articles,

- [Location API on android.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html)
- [Location API on Java ME.](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/)

Comment: Yes I know that location api are available for android and java but i want to find location for those mobiles who don't support java/android apps as given example of nokia 3310 which can't run such applications . so can u tell if there is a way to find location for such type of old mobiles?

Comment: Sorry. You can't. Because you install the application on such kind of mobiles. Without installation its not possible to get. :)

Comment: I am pretty sure java cannot see the IMEI number with or without Location services

Comment: @Steve , You can get the [IMEI number](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-A1F90B63-5F14-4829-BCA1-A23B925CF670.html) on S60 3rd Edition FP2 or higher and Series 40 3rd Edition FP1 or higher mobiles.